# Cannot find Primary outlet to Load

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an app that I cannot get to load a simple component. I think its something simple but I am totally missing it.

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {PageStat}   from './PageStat';
import {PageStatService} from './pageStatService';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'PageStats',
    template: '<h2>You Made it!</h2>',
    styleUrls: ['./basestyle.css']
})
export class PageStatsComponent implements OnInit{
    pagestats: PageStat[];
    selectedStat: PageStat;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private pagestatservice: PageStatService){}
    getPageStatList(){
    this.pagestatservice.getPageStats().then(pagestats => this.pagestats = pagestats)

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPageStatList();
    }
    onSelect(selectpagestat: PageStat){
        this.selectedStat = selectpagestat;
    }
    gotoDetail(): void {
        this.router.navigate(['/detail', this.selectedStat.refid]);
    }
}
```

and this is my app-routing:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PageStatsComponent }      from './PageStats.component';
import { PageStatDetailComponent }  from './pagestat-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/pageStats', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'pagestats/detail/:id', component: PageStatDetailComponent },
  { path: 'pageStats',     component: PageStatsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I have tried stripping different parts out of the component and nothing seems to change the outcome. I have attempted to clone this off of the 'tour of heroes' example. I see a lot of references to a "router outlet" but the tour of heroes app didn't have one and it works so I'm not 100% sure why or where I would need to place one.

EDIT: The full error: Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'PageStatsComponent'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

somewhere in your HTML so that it knows where to display the HTML for the current route.

In your top level component do this ..

```
template: '<h2>here is the rest of my HTML for the top level component</h2><router-outlet></router-outlet>'
```

Comment: I got it. The thing that was confusing me when I was trying the router outlet was I misunderstood where <router-outlet> went. I didn't see one in the tour of heroes app where I thought it went so I assumed they didn't have one. Your comment about the "Top Level" component clued me in. The PageStats Component wasn't my top level. Thanks!